# Copy data and re-order columns and paste in to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry to post a question without any code but not sure where to begin with. I have to copy data from a work book and paste in destination workbook by re-ordering the columns before pasting in destination workbook. Both workbooks have numbers in their first column so that if a column has number 5 in source workbook then that column should be pasted in destination workbook where top column has number 5. We also have few columns in source workbook where there wont be any number in first column as that data is not required in destination. I have 1-20 columns.data starts from 3rd row and to be pasted in 3rd row in destination  workbook.Can someone help please.

Comment: Hi @Sharmila, Try giving a visual explanation of your columns, they would help better to understand the problem and gather a possible solution for someone who could answer it.

Comment: Source workbook top column - 2 8 4 7 N N 1 5 6 3 N 9 Destination Wbtop columns  -   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9    Column header with N will be empty which means that column data not required to paste in destination workbook. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have a sample worksheet I just can give a hint. If I were you I would use the `Range.Find()` Method to find the Column I am looking for. Then you can insert the data at this position.

Some more Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

```vb
Sub Find()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = YourTable.Range("3:3").Find("5", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If (Not rng Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.Print rng.Column
    Else
        Debug.Print "Nothing found"
    End If

End Sub
```